# How to inject a fake implementation of a class providing no interface and no virtual methods?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, discord.net

I'm using the Discord.Net package offering me the `DiscordSocketClient` class, which currently is a Singleton in my DI container. I need several methods from the instance

- `Task LoginAsync(TokenType tokenType, string token, bool validateToken = true)`
- `Task StartAsync()`
- `Task LogoutAsync()`
- `Task StopAsync()`

Given this example class consuming the methods

```
public sealed class ConsumingClass
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _discordSocketClient;
    
    public ConsumingClass(DiscordSocketClient discordSocketClient)
    {
        _discordSocketClient = discordSocketClient;
    }
    
    public override async Task Initialize(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _discordSocketClient.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "my-token");
        await _discordSocketClient.StartAsync();
    }
    
    public override async Task TearDown(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _discordSocketClient.LogoutAsync();
        await _discordSocketClient.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

I want to create tests using XUnit and Moq to ensure the instance of `ConsumingClass` works as expected.

Unfortunately `DiscordSocketClient` does not offer an interface so I can't inject a mock implementation to my tests.

Also the methods are not virtual, so it is not possible to create an instance of `Mock<DiscordSocketClient>` and use `.Setup()` to setup mock implementations.

So how can I verify in my testcase, that the client methods have been called once? E.g. `_discordSocketClientMock.Verify(discordSocketClient => discordSocketClient.LoginAsync(), Times.Once());`

Do I have to create an interface `IMyDiscordSocketClient` providing those methods and a class  another class `MyDiscordSocketClient` inheriting from `DiscordSocketClient` and implementing the interface and use that? Or are there any better ways?

Answer (score 2):

If `DiscordSocketClient` does not have (public) virtual members, you cannot really derive from it either. Your last suggestion is however probably still the best possibility you have, except that `MyDiscordSocketClient` should not derive from `DiscordSocketClient`, but aggregate one.

```cs
public class MyDiscordSocketClient: IMyDiscordSocketClient
{
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    public MyDiscordSocketClient(DiscordSocketClient client)
    {
        _client = _client;
    }
    
    public async Task Initialize(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         _client.Initialize(cancellationToken);
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But by doing so, I still can't check if `LoginAsync` and `StartAsync` have been called, right? So the custom wrapper wouldn't provide any benefits

Comment: @Question3r. Sure you can. Since your `ConsumingClass` would then take an `IMyDiscordSocketClient` in the constructor instead of an `DiscordSocketClient` you can provide a mock for it. You can't unit test `MyDiscordSocketClient` but that would serve no purpose, because it does not contain any logic.